# Blank ListView with no errors in Logcat - Android & custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I've been trying to create a listView that display event items, only it isn't showing anything. I've pretty much just followed [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html) example. My dq.getAllEventsCategory() method returns an Arraylist of Event Items.

Here's my Activity:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
DatabaseQueries dq = new DatabaseQueries(this);
private ArrayList<Event> eventDetails;
public String typeSearchTerm;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);


    Intent i = getIntent();
   typeSearchTerm = i.getStringExtra(String.valueOf(R.string.event_type_extra));



    //TRY TO FILL THE ARRAYLIST WITH ALL EVENTS
    DatabaseQueries dq = new DatabaseQueries(this);
    try {
        //eventDetails = dq.getAllEventsCategory(typeSearchTerm);
        eventDetails = dq.getAllEvents();
        Log.d("ARRAY SIZE", eventDetails.size() + "");
        Date d = new Date();
       // Event e = new Event("BBQ", "bottle cap",d, "This is an event", "www.google.com", d, d );
       // eventDetails.add(e);
       // Log.d("Array Size after", eventDetails.size() + "");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final ListView lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);

    lv1.setAdapter(new eventItemAdapter(this, eventDetails));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Event objEvent = (Event)o;
            Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + objEvent.getEventName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class eventItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private static ArrayList<Event> eventDetails;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static final SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //dd-MM-yyyy
    private static final SimpleDateFormat parseTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");//hh:mm a

    public eventItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> results) {
        eventDetails = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return eventDetails.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return eventDetails.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.eventDetailName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDetailsName);
            holder.eventDetailLocation = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDetailsLocation);
            holder.eventDetailDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDetailsDate);
            holder.eventDetailStartTime = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventDetailsStartTime);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.eventDetailName.setText(eventDetails.get(position).getEventName());
        holder.eventDetailLocation.setText(eventDetails.get(position).getEventLocation());
        Date temp = new Date();
        temp = eventDetails.get(position).getEventDate();
        holder.eventDetailDate.setText(parser.format(temp));
        Date tempTime = new Date();
        tempTime = eventDetails.get(position).getEventStartTime();
        holder.eventDetailStartTime.setText(parseTime.format(tempTime));

        //Return the current view
        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView eventDetailName;
        TextView eventDetailLocation;
        TextView eventDetailDate;
        TextView eventDetailStartTime;
    } }
```

This is the item View:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventDetailsName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#33CC33"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Time: "
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailsStartTime"
                    android:layout_column="3" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date: "
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/eventDetailsDate"
                    android:layout_column="3" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location: "
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/eventDetailsLocation"
            android:layout_column="3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the the actual ListView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/categoryListView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

Code for getAllEventsCategory():

```
public ArrayList<Event> getAllEventsCategory(String category) throws ParseException {
    SQLiteDatabase dq = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Event> global = new ArrayList<Event>();


    String query = "SELECT e." + EVENT_ID + ", e." + EVENT_NAME + ", e." + EVENT_SOCIETY_ID + ", e."
            + EVENT_LOCATION + ", e." + EVENT_LINK + ", e." + EVENT_START_TIME + ", e."
            + EVENT_END_TIME + ", et." + EVENT_TYPE + " FROM " + TABLE_EVENT + " e LEFT JOIN "
            + TABLE_HAS_CATEGORY + " h ON e." + EVENT_ID + " = h." + HAS_EVENT_ID
            + " JOIN " + TABLE_EVENT_TYPE + " et ON h." + HAS_EVENT_TYPE_ID + " = et."
            + EVENT_TYPE_ID + " where et." + EVENT_TYPE + " = \"" + category + "\";";

    Log.d("QUERY ", "" + query);

    Cursor cursor = dq.rawQuery(query, null);
    int numRows = cursor.getCount();

    //for loop to add each event to the arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        Event e = new Event();

        e.setEventID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        e.setEventName(cursor.getString(1));
        e.setSocietyID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        e.setEventLocation(cursor.getString(4));

        String myDate = cursor.getString(5);
        e.setEventDate(parser.parse(myDate));
        e.setEventDescription(cursor.getString(6));
        e.setEventLink(cursor.getString(7));


        String myStartTime = cursor.getString(8);
        e.setEventStartTime(parseTime.parse(myStartTime));

        String myEndTime = cursor.getString(9);
        e.setEventEndTime(parseTime.parse(myEndTime));


        global.add(e);


        if (i < numRows) {

            cursor.moveToPosition(i + 1);
        }

        if (i > numRows) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }


    }
    return global;
}
```

I've also tried without a specific category search (as in just using the arraylist returned by my getAllEvents method) but i'm still getting a null pointer exception. I get a null pointer exception with getAllEvents and an empty/blank listview with getAllEventsCategory

getAllEvents() method:

```
public ArrayList<Event> getAllEvents() throws ParseException {
    SQLiteDatabase dq = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Event> global = new ArrayList<Event>();




    Log.d("QUERY ", "" + query);

    Cursor cursor = dq.rawQuery(query, null);
    int numRows = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       //for loop to add each event to the arraylist
       for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
           Event e = new Event();

           e.setEventID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
           e.setEventName(cursor.getString(1));
           e.setSocietyID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
           e.setEventLocation(cursor.getString(3));

           String myDate = cursor.getString(4);
           e.setEventDate(parser.parse(myDate));
           e.setEventDescription(cursor.getString(5));
           if(cursor.getString(6) != null) {
               e.setEventLink(cursor.getString(6));
           }else{
               e.setEventLink("");
           }

           String myStartTime = cursor.getString(7);
           e.setEventStartTime(parseTime.parse(myStartTime));

           Date date = new Date();
           date.setTime(0);

           if(cursor.getString(8) != null){
               String myEndTime = cursor.getString(8);
               e.setEventEndTime(parseTime.parse(myEndTime));
           }else{
               e.setEventEndTime(date);
           }



           global.add(e);


           if (i < numRows) {

               cursor.moveToPosition(i + 1);
           }

           if (i > numRows) {
               cursor.moveToFirst();
           }


       }

   }else{
       Log.d("Results", "no results");
   }
    Log.d("Array size", "" + global.size());
    return global;
}
```

[This](http://i.imgur.com/bGHndPo.png) is my logcat. the d log "Array size" is the size of the array that should be the parameter for the lv1.setAdapter() method

Comment: When you say it isn't showing anything, what do you mean? Is the screen just black? The more you can tell us, the better the chance we could help you.

Comment: Please check your 'eventDetails' size (System.out.println(eventDetails.size();)

Comment: not black, it just shows an empty screen like [this](http://imgur.com/bmuzzxC)

Comment: @Vladimir Alright. Well that probably explains it. My getAllEventsCategory method is returning an empty arraylist. If the arraylist weren't empty, should it still be display something? or is something wrong in my code

Comment: @vn2456 seems to me code is fine, problem is in 'getAllEventsCategory()'

Comment: @VladimirKulyk Alright cheers! thanks for that. It does seem to be the problem.

Comment: @vn2456 as Abhijeet Gupta said you may use wrong ListView ID ("listViewCategory",  "categoryListView"). Did you check this?

Comment: @VladimirKulyk I've fixed the issues that Abhijeet mentioned, but now I'm getting a null pointer exception: attempt to read from null array. Which I think might be at lv1.setAdapter. Any ideas on what the problem is? I've added some dummy objects into eventDetails so it shouldn't be null (size() isn't 0).

Comment: @vn2456 i did not see your changes. Need to be update.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk  It seems that the dummy objects I added was causing the null pointer exception. When I commented them out, I'm back to my original problem where the listview isn't displaying anything. I'll update my OP with what i've done now, which is just replacing the getAllEventsCategory() method with  a getAllEvents() method. But yeah, using the getAllEvents() method i'm still getting a null pointer exception

Comment: @vn2456 one more thing, try to make ListView global (public/private) and not final.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must consider these points while using listview,

- **The height of list item view should be "wrap_content"**.If you make it "match_parent", the first row take all space on device and there is no room for the rest of row.
- **The height of Listview should be "match_parent"**.If you make it "wrap_content", the recycling concept of list view is not used because it creates all rows of listview as listview display first time.It also affects the scrolling of listview and consume a lot of memory.

You use the wrong Id for the listview in java class.The listview id in XML is "**listViewCategory**" and listview id used in java class is "**categoryListView**".

One thing more is that,please make sure that there must be items in array (eventDetails) at the time of setAdapter().

Comment: ok I've fixed those issues you mentioned, but i accidentally posted the wrong XML for the listView i used, I actually did use a listview called categoryListView . I'll update my OP. Only problem now is  that I get a null pointer exception: attempt to read from null array. The thing is, before I set the adapter, I made sure there was an event object in the array ( using  eventDetails.add(event)) but it's now giving me this error. Any ideas why?

Comment: can you please attach the code for the getAllEventsCategory(typeSearchTerm) method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed your problem? I found that you have placed a table row outside your table layout in the item view.